# SE Asia Standard Time zone showing Unparseable date exception during parsing date format

Tags: java, datetime, jakarta-ee

I try with different timezone in date, that all working fine, but **SE Asia Standard Time** is not parsing with the full date showing Unparseable date exception.

```
String date="Sun Jan 18 2015 22:11:44 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (zzzz)");
        try{
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(sdf.parse(date).getTime()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Just to note: "SE Asia Standard Time" comes from Microsoft, see [TimeZone](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Java this timezone is called "*Indochina Time*"

I think the name of the timezone is not nessessary to parse the correct date because you have also the time offset in your string. So removing the timezone name from the string should do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "Sun Jan 18 2015 22:11:44 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)";

    date = date.substring(0, date.indexOf("("));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(sdf.parse(date).getTime()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay, here i need to convert SE Asia Standard Time this timezone because this date come from photo file, i want that in timestamp format

Comment: I think you can remove the timezone name from your string because you have the offset for parsing the correct time. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

"SE Asia Standard Time" is not one of the supported timezones. For GMT+7, here are the available timezones:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.asList(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()).stream()
            .map(TimeZone::getTimeZone)
            .filter(zone -> zone.getRawOffset() == 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            .forEach(zone -> System.out.printf("%-20s  %s\n", zone.getID(), zone.getDisplayName()));
}
```

```
Antarctica/Davis      Davis Time
Asia/Bangkok          Indochina Time
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh      Indochina Time
Asia/Hovd             Hovd Time
Asia/Jakarta          West Indonesia Time
Asia/Krasnoyarsk      Krasnoyarsk Time
Asia/Novokuznetsk     Krasnoyarsk Time
Asia/Phnom_Penh       Indochina Time
Asia/Pontianak        West Indonesia Time
Asia/Saigon           Indochina Time
Asia/Vientiane        Indochina Time
Etc/GMT-7             GMT+07:00
Indian/Christmas      Christmas Island Time
VST                   Indochina Time
```

Comment: this timezone come from client side so how can i handle in java?

Comment: Where is the client getting it from? Couldn't you just use the Z offset that they provide? Looks like DirkNM suggested the same.

Comment: Would suggest having the client use ISO compliant timezone formats or just use the offset that they provided and forget the timezone name.